# Is there a way of importing fonts through css in ie7?

Tags: css, fonts, import, internet-explorer-7

My problem is pretty simple, but I just can't solve it by myself. Does anybody know how to import fonts in ie7?
The code that I use and works in all navigators, except ie is:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: "Interstate";
    src: url("interstate_regular.ttf");
}
```

All that I found is that ie7 can't support it, but it's better to be sure of it.

Well, if anyone knows how to solve this (or not), I'd be really glad. ;)

Comment: IE7 offers partial support for CSS @font-face! Try http://www.microsoft.com/typography/WEFT.mspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain IE7 supports @font-face but (forgive me, been a while since I ever worried about IE7 so memory is fuzzy) I believe there is a bug in the way IE 7 and 8 process the URL's.

Your best bet is to use the [@font-face generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) at fontsquirrel... it will create a css class with all the necessary fixes to make it work in as many browsers as supported.

Comment: I took a look on @font-face generator, it helps a lot, besides it generates lots of junkie! ;)
I took a look on this page: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/at-fontface and found out that ie5.5+ "only works with EOT (Embedded OpenType Font) files". So, I could solve it. ;)

Anyway, thanks really much! =D

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely try [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator), it will help you generate your font-face code and the needed files for every browser.

If it doesn't work, you'll be "sure of it" :-)